# Secure port 8000 on Ubuntu OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl

I just followed the following tutorial :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-certbot-nginx
sudo certbot --nginx -d yourdomain.com -d www.yourdomain.com

# Only valid for 90 days, test the renewal process with
certbot renew --dry-run
```

This did work but only for the client which runs on the main domain. But I also have an API running on port 8000. When I visit mydomain.com:8000 it does redirect me to https but it shows the following error: 
[image]

Basically it loads forever.

I already allowed https in my firewall. I mean the base domain works fine it's just the port 8000 that doesnt work with https , it does work with http..

```
server {

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html/dexhub/client/build;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name www.iprofitmizer.com iprofitmizer.com; # managed by Certbot

        error_page 404 /;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        location /api {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        }
```

Comment: What's the output of `netstat -tulpen | grep 8000`?

Comment: @digijay : `tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       632515     16185/node /var/www
` Color of the port is shown red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get to your nodejs API would be to define it via a proxy like this

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
}
```

in your nginx virtual host configuration (e.g. `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my-site.conf`). You should then be able to access your API via https://iprofitmizer.com/api
and certbot auto-renewal should also work.

Otherwise you would have to integrate TLS support into your nodejs application.

Comment: I added my nginx configuration in the question with what you've told me to do, still nothing sadly

Comment: fixed it, thanks for the answer. After figuring out how to fix the reverse proxy it worked

Comment: Cool, glad I could help! What exactly did you have to fix?